how to terminate the subthread it is running in while(1) when main thred is going terminate
i have an process it is creating the sub thread and detaching from main thred.
the sub thread is running in infinate loop.
suppose my main thread is terminated by some reason then this sub thread is not terminating,how to ressolve this in c++.
My code was like this
void fun() {
    while (1) {
        // do work
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread thread_(fun);
    thread_.detach();
}


Related It's OS-specific what happens to detached thread on exit, but on most platform it will be killed on parent exit.

don't detach it. Detaching a thread is rarely a good idea. And in the rare cases where it is a good idea you will eventually realize that it really wasnt a good idea. Anyhow, your example has any details stripped off, hence it is almost impossible to help. Please provide a [mcve]

you can use a condition varibable, or an atomic_flag and change while(1) to while(run) instead of detaching it

Use a atomic boolean flag. Check if the flag is set in the thread while loop, if yes, then break out of the loop. You can set the atomic flag in the main thread whenever needed.

IMHO while(1) is almost always wrong. You should be able to control the thread termination. It should be while(end_condition) with end_condition being something you have control over, it may simply be an std::atomic_bool that you would set to false when you want to stop the loop (and thus exiting the thread).

The clean and portable solution is to use std::stop_token or some std::atomic<bool> to indicate when the thread should stop. See the linked duplicate.
